# Ways to fix muttable borrowing of self in arguments to function that borrows muttable self

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have some code like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=99520256edc5573ee2241c413d86a41f)). Why does the compiler think it's a problem? How can i solve this problem without adding new variable that storing argument as the compiler tells?

Code:

```rust
struct A {}

impl A {
    fn foo(&mut self, i: i32) -> i32 {
        i
    }
    
    fn bar(&mut self) -> i32 {
        1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = A{};
    b.foo(b.bar());
}
```

Error:

```text
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `b` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:15:11
   |
15 |     b.foo(b.bar());
   |     ------^^^^^^^-
   |     | |   |
   |     | |   second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     | first borrow later used by call
   |     first mutable borrow occurs here
   |
help: try adding a local storing this argument...
  --> src/main.rs:15:11
   |
15 |     b.foo(b.bar());
   |           ^^^^^^^
help: ...and then using that local as the argument to this call
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     b.foo(b.bar());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please embed the full code in the question. Playground links are nice, but are not searchable etc.

Comment: Why don't you want to introduce a new variable? As for "why", the compiler explains it well.

Comment: As for me, creating a variable for its one-time use does not make sense. This, although a little, clogs the code. I can’t understand why the compiler doesn’t like this, because self doesn’t have a lifetime

Comment: 1. Why do you even need a mutable reference to `self` in the first place? You're not mutating any state in the struct. Just get rid of `mut`. 2. "Creating a variable for its one-time use does not make sense" it does: in that case the mutable borrow is finished and the stored variable is just an `int32` in your example code you borrow `self` twice in a single expression, so splitting it in half fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking apart that your methods do not need to be `&mut` and that is just for the example.

> How can i solve this problem without adding new variable that storing argument as the compiler tells?

**At the moment, you can't**. The way is to move the inner result, so the borrow is unlocked on the next call:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut b = A{};
    let i = b.bar();
    b.foo(i);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf1f3010ad1535bd5c40bbd8d40e8cec)

Comment: do you know what the reason for this behavior is, and whether it is considered something they'll fix in the future? The naive assumption would be the outter borrow starts after the inner borrow has finished, after all

Comment: It is a known issue in the borrow checker, should be fixed in the next iteration called polonious afaik

Comment: That is very nice to hear! Do you know whether there is a tracking issue on Github for that?